# Laravel: cannot use php artisan migrate with Amazon RDS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I followed every tutorial from Amazon to set up the RDS Database then to set up the VPC, the subnet, and the Security Groups but I still can't connect to the Database using Laravel command.

However, I can connect to the Database using MySQLWorkbench...

This is the error I got when I use the command "php artisan migrate"

[image]

Every help will be more than appreciate, thank you Guys.

Answer (score 5):

I'm taking these settings right out of my RDS instance and the Laravel application that uses it.

The first thing you have to do after setting up your RDS database is to allow the database instance to be accessed publicly. This can be done from your AWS console by going to RDS > DB Instances > **your database instance** > Modify (top left corner). Then scroll down to the Network and Security section and select 'Yes' for public accessibility.

[image: Network and Security > Public accessibility]

Also double check your Security groups to make sure there is a rule allowing incoming connections to port 3306.

In your Laravel application's `.env` file and update the database values.
`DB_HOST` should contain the endpoint specified on the Connectivity and security section of the RDS dashboard. `DB_PORT` should remain at `3306`. Then specify the  database name in `DB_DATABASE` and the database credentials in `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`.

These are the settings I'm using to connect my Laravel application to an RDS MySQL database.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to say but it looks like you have the incorrect DB name.
Double check your RDS db name and the environment variable `DB_DATABASE`